# Error when importing lib package in Python

Tags: python, installation, package, reinforcement-learning

I've installed (`pip install lib`) the lib package on python 3.

When I run the following script:

```
from lib import environ, data, models, common, validation
```

I get the following error:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 11 from ignite.contrib.handlers import tensorboard_logger as tb_logger
> 12
> ---> 13 from lib import environ, data, models, common, validation
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'environ' from 'lib'
> (/home/darfeder/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lib/**init**.py)

I am preparing an environment for reinforcement learning.

Comment: Did you try setting the environment in [venv](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/venv.html)?

Comment: Hi Franco Morero, I think so. I've created a conda virtual environment from terminal and run jupyter notebook from there.

Comment: I think I should modify the init.py

Comment: Hi Franco Morero I've created a venv instead of a conda env but the problem is the same